# Make nginx serve index.html if requested url is not found without using error_page

Tags: nginx

I have nginx configured to serve a single page React.js app as static content. react-router handles routing in browser.

To make it possible for users to enter all urls (not just the domain `example.com`, but also urls like `example.com/some/path`, `example.com/some/other/path`, etc.) directly in the address bar, I am doing,

```
error_page 404 /index.html
```

This works perfectly fine everywhere except in Internet Explorer. IE shows 404 page for this.

How do I configure nginx, such that it serves index.html, if the request path cannot be matched to a file in the root directory.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that `IE` showing you cached version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a job for `try_files`.

```
try_files $uri /index.html;
```

`$uri` will load any static resources if they are present and accessible; for any inaccessible URLs, `/index.html` will be served (with a 200).

Comment: Which one would be better approach `try_files` or `error_page 404 =200 /index.html` as mentioned by Alex_hha below? and why? Thanks

Comment: The end result is _probably_ the same, but nobody really expects `error_page` to be used in that manner, so it will be confusing to anyone else who looks at it; while `try_files` is well understood and intended to be used this way.

Comment: Also, one day you would want to send 404 (e.g. for unknown image) and with `error_page` “hack” you'll get big problem…

Answer (score 0):

As workaround you can use

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.net;

    root /vhosts/default/public_html;

    error_page 404 =200 /index.html;

    location / {
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

> Is it possible that IE showing you cached version?

it seems default behavior for IE. At least for IE11 on Windows 7

P.S.
It turns out that your index.html MUST be 512+ bytes